# GAE: testing download of blobs with testbed and webtest

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm using the blobstore with my Google App Engine app, and everything is working fine on the production server and the development server.  Testing with testbed and [webtest](http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/), however, isn't working...

In my tests, the blob exists as I can access it like this:

```
blob = self.blobstore_stub.storage._blobs[key]
```

When I try to download a blob in my tests like this

```
response = self.app.get("/blob-download/2")
```

my blobstore download handler never gets called and I get a 404 error (but the link works on the dev or prod servers).

I suspect this is an error with testbed or webtest...

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong, or if this is an error with testbed/webtest what a good work around might be so that I can test this part of my code?

---

Here is some info about how I am setting up my tests.

```
import unittest
from webtest import TestApp
from google.appengine.ext import db, testbed
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map

class ExampleTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.setup_env(app_id="stv")
        self.testbed.activate()
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()
        self.testbed.init_taskqueue_stub()
        self.testbed.init_mail_stub()
        self.testbed.init_blobstore_stub()
        self.app = TestApp(main.application)
        apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub("datastore_v3").Clear()
        self.taskqueue_stub = apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub('taskqueue')
        self.mail_stub = apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub('mail')
        self.blobstore_stub = apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub('blobstore')

   def testBlob(self):
        # create blob using files.blobstore.create
        response = self.app.get("/blob-download/2") # This returns 404
        self.assertEqual(response.body, "content of blob") # This fails
```

---

This is the relevant portion of app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.application
```

---

This is the relevant portion of main.py:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [
     ('/blob-download/([^/]+)?', views.BlobDownload),
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell about the routing without having the routing from main.application and app.yaml available.

I suspect that you configured "/blob-download" in app.yaml of which webtest is unaware, it only knows about the routing you configured in main.application.

**update**: Now that we now app.yaml is not the cause, let's move on. What would help is to see your handler. Blobstore serving responses are handled differently then the usual responses. You, as a developer, add the blob key as a header to the response. The App Engine backend checks for this header end and if it finds it takes over the serving of the blob. You can check out the dev_appserver implementation here:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_blobstore.py#214.

This means you can't actually test serving of blobs without having dev_appserver or appserver processing the requests - which means testbed + webtest won't help you here (it doesn't explain the 404 though).

What you could do is run a full end-to-end test, for example with gaedriver: http://code.google.com/p/gaedriver/

Comment: Hi schuppe, thanks for your response.  I don't think this is the problem but I updated my question with more details about app.yaml and main.py.

Comment: @schuppe how would it even be possible to define something in app.yaml without mapping it to a handler in main.application? you can send everything to main.application but that mapping has to be the more specific one.

Comment: @aschmid00 I wanted to check if Jeff had a different handler defined in app.yaml which handled requests to '/blob-download/' before main.application got to it. Patterns defined in app.yaml are evaluated in the order they appear. Would he have had a handler defined for something that matches '/blob-download/' before a possible catch-all '.*'-main it would have been an easy explanation. But with Jeff's update it looks like that is not the case..

Comment: @schuppe i understand but i guess (and hope so) that if he would handle "/blob-download" with another handler he would know about it also because he says that the app works on dev and production. the tests do not.

Comment: @schuppe, I don't understand what you mean by "You, as a developer, add the blob key as a header to the response" as I don't do this.  I serve blobs as described here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob.  Also, my blob download handler never gets called. That is the primary problem I am trying to fix and I updated my question to try to make that clearer.

Comment: @Jeff By using self.send_blob(blob_info) you are calling a function that puts the blob key into the response headers: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/webapp/blobstore_handlers.py#260. In any case, can you provide your test function as well?

Comment: @schuppe, There isn't much interesting in the test function...  requesting a blob produces a a 404, but I updated my question with relevant details about a test that would produce this problem.

Comment: @kekito, I pretty sure there is something wrong in your routing setup or request handling because I could get a basic example working. It's too long to fit in here (http://pastebin.com/FQFH1Rx6), but it's basically a stripped-down version of what you provided plus some code added to fill the gaps. The test itself doesn't pass, but the handler is called for sure. Sorry that I can't be of more help.

Comment: @schuppe, thanks for putting that together. It doesn't return the blob for me though and you didn't check the response.  Could you try this and let me know if the test fails?: http://pastebin.com/p8pY8BsE

Comment: @Kekito Your tests run but fail, which is too be expected - just like the one I pasted. Why? As I explained earlier, "Blobstore serving responses are handled differently then the usual responses .. This means you can't actually test serving of blobs without having dev_appserver or appserver processing the requests - which means testbed + webtest won't help you here". At least you now know that the 404 is due to some piece of your code, because the trivia snippets return a 200.

Comment: @schuppe, I see you point.  Turning a 404 into a 200 that doesn't return the blob unfortunately doesn't help much though since the whole point is to be able to test my use of the blob store which I apparently can't do. :(